# Elasticsearch: can elasticsearch do a update by query and return the results?

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to do two things: 1. Update docs by the query 2. Get the docs found by the same query. I can do it with 2 API requests. But for simplicity and performance reasons I want it be done in 1 API request. This feature is analogous to `findAndModify` in mongodb or `UPDATE ... RETURNING` in postgres.

I found an API parameter `_source: true` in the docs (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.x/docs-update-by-query.html#docs-update-by-query-api-query-params). It sounds like it is what I am looking for, except that it have no effect.

Is there an update and return API in elasticsearch?

Comment: I also tried it with _source=true on the latest version of ES and it doesn't seems to be working as it should